# Button inceasing count in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I need some help as I am very new to JavaScript and Vue thanks :)

```js
<template>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @click="count += 1">
        <p v-text="count"></p>
    </button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                count: 1
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: When the button is pressed the number doesn't increase

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something when I saw your question, I know that is a bit late but I think that this is what you were looking for:

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    counter: 0
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example-1">
  <button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</button>
  <p> {{ counter }} </p>
</div>
```